# Апстарт для MongoDB

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Всем привет.
Поставил сервер для приложения. БД - MondoDB. Всё работало хорошо, но что то пошло не так, и база начала крашиться постоянно. Пока разбираться нет времени, а приложение должно работать. Можно ли как-нибудь в Ubuntu запускать сервер mongo после краша автоматически?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` добавить:

```
respawn
respawn limit 20 30
```

Это будет перезапускать сервис монги 20 раз, с интервалом в 30 секунд.

Но лучше конечно разобраться с причиной краша.

Comment: Владимир, а после этого нужно ли перезапускать что то?

Comment: `service mongodb stop`, `service mongodb start` должно хватить.

Comment: На всякий случай - в новых версиях сервис называется mongod (без b) (соответственно файл конфига `/etc/init/mongod.conf`)

Comment: Спасибо Вам, буду пробовать